# TFS 2012 Extensibility - TF201077 Work Item Type cannot be found

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm working on a piece of extensibility code that retrieves a `WorkItemCollection` of custom work item types and attempts to inspect a custom field from it.  I have connected to TFS from the code using my TfsService account and I'm using a `WorkItemStore` object to perform a query using a static WIQL string.  The query returns one result (as I currently have one test change record loaded in DEV).

```
public bool ChangeExists(ChangeRecord record)
{
    var tfsChanges = wis.Query("SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [Work Item Type] = 'Change Record'");

    foreach (WorkItem tfschg in tfsChanges)
    {
        if(tfschg.Fields["ABC.ReportingTeam.CustomFields.ChgNumber"].Value == record.ChangeNumber) //Error here
        {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When executing the code, the `WorkItemStore` returns a `WorkItemCollection`.  When I attempt to access any WorkItem in the collection I receive the following error:

> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: TF201077: The work item type  cannot be found.
>   It may have been renamed or destroyed.

I'm somewhat mystified as to why this is happening, because I have a Change Record work item type already loaded into TFS.  See a snippet of the XML and screenshot below:

```
<Witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0" xmlns:Witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">
  <WORKITEMTYPE name="Change Record">
    <DESCRIPTION>Represents a Change Order in SDM </DESCRIPTION>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD name="Change Start Date" refname="ABC.ReportingTeam.CustomFields.ChgStartDate" type="DateTime" reportable="detail">
        <REQUIRED />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Change End Date" refname="ABC.ReportingTeam.CustomFields.ChgEndDate" type="DateTime" reportable="detail">
        <REQUIRED />
      </FIELD>
      <FIELD name="Change Number" refname="ABC.ReportingTeam.CustomFields.ChgNumber" type="String" reportable="detail" />
     </FIELDS>
```

[image: Change Record exists in TFS]

My Work Item Type exists, my custom field exists, and my work item template has been successfully loaded in TFS.  Why is my code throwing a DeniedOrDoesNotExist error?

Comment: Due to you have proven that the item exits, I guess you are in the "denied" part of this error. Can you verify that the account you use for the C# request has full access to the work items. As far as I know, simple write or read permissions are not sufficient.

Comment: @Herdo I have tried this with both my TfsService account and my personal TFS account (which is a Project Administrator) and both encounter the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the where clause (or replace it with an id check) to see if you can retrieve any Workitems at all?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the change number to the query directly and just check result count? Then it is not necessary to iterate through all Change Records, what might get a lot in future.

```
var tfsChanges = wis.Query("SELECT * FROM WorkItems WHERE [Work Item Type] = 'Change Record' AND ["ABC.ReportingTeam.CustomFields.ChgNumber"] = '"+record.ChangeNumber+"'");
```

For testing if you really have a permission issue, try to get one of the Change Records you created and you know the ID:

```
WorkItem wi = wis.GetWorkItem(WorkItemID);
```